# adding post edit link via jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I use my own file caching stsytem on my wordpress site. I want to add posts edit link for admin users. But if you logged with admin account when you visit a page, the system create a cached html page for my all visistors.

I just want to display edit link for my admin users. I think we can add this via Jquery ?

But how ?

Here is the edit link php function;

```
<?php edit_post_link('edit', '<p>', '</p>'); ?>
```

Comment: <?php echo edit_post_link('edit', '<p>', '</p>'); ?>

Comment: @JLP the nature of the function `edit_post_link()` is to `echo the HTML`, not to `return it`. In order to save it as a string so it's not echo'd immediately, you'd do `get_edit_post_link()` as is common with most WP functions.

Comment: ok, whats the result of edit_post_link() ? use var_dump() to see

Comment: The result is that it's instantaneously echo'd and must be used within the loop. If you don't, then you need to leverage `get_edit_post_link()` and pass in the `id of the post`. Otherwise, you'll get a PHP Warning.

Comment: show exactly the result plz ...

Comment: @JLP I don't know what results you want me to show you. Try and use `edit_post_link()` from `functions.php` and let me know how that works for you, because it won't, you'll need to do `global $post; echo get_edit_post_link($post->ID, 'edit')` to get the desired effect.

Comment: whats the of var_dump(get_edit_post_link($post->ID, 'edit'));

Comment: thanks for all comment but, my wordpress root index.php file, like here : http://codepaste.net/gf9qmi i should check is user logged before including cache. But didint work.